# Python mocked side effect is returning a mocked object instead of the value

Tags: python, unit-testing, side-effects

I did some research on side effects and as I understand it it's supposed to have the values pulled from an iterable on each call. But I'm not sure why it's not printing 1, 2 but instead

```
<MagicMock name='bar' id='4448537616'>
<MagicMock name='bar' id='4448537616'>
```

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'foo'
        pass

from unittest import mock

def test_foo():
    f = Foo()
    with mock.patch.object(f, 'bar', side_effect=[1,2]) :
        print(f.bar)
        print(f.bar)

test_foo()
```

But if I do `f.bar()` I get the actual value, but `bar` is supposed to be an attribute not a function.

Is my understanding of how side_effects work incorrect?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? Im running into the exact same problem, and I cant seem to get a straight answer. The only difference is that Im trying to mock a function which changes its return value depending on the arguments.

Comment: Same issue for me, not returning correct value

Answer (score 1):

As you said it yourself, `side_effect` is "supposed to have the values pulled from an iterable *on each call*". The keywords here are "on each call".

`mock.patch.object(f, 'bar', side_effect=[1,2])` makes `f.bar` a mock object with a side effect that makes `f.bar` return the next value from `[1,2]` *on each call*, and by *call* it means to call `f.bar` with parentheses, `f.bar()`.

To achieve your desired behavior of making `f.bar` itself return a different value on each access (not call), you can temporarily make `Foo.bar` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) instead, with the getter function being a mock object with a side effect of `[1, 2]`.

Since `Foo.bar` is not predefined in your code, and `mock.patch.object` can only patch an existing attribute, you would have to manage the lifecycle of this mock `Foo.bar` yourself by creating and deleting it explicitly:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'foo'
        pass

from unittest import mock

def test_foo():
    Foo.bar = property(mock.Mock(side_effect=[1, 2]), mock.Mock())
    f = Foo()
    print(f.bar)
    print(f.bar)
    del Foo.bar

test_foo()
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/apXG5m